# Can someone provide a clear example on using VSCode’s Configuration API to read a config file in a workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Can anyone help me with how to use the configuration API to read in workspace settings?

Hi, everyone.

I’ve been beating my head against the wall for a while.

GOAL: user makes “foo.config” file with “connectionString” parameter.

From my extension, I could read this connectionString and use it to perform functions.

This seems like it should be simple, but I haven’t had luck.

Comment: VSCode's configuration API only covers its own setting files (like `.vscode/settings.json`). If you want to parse other settings (XML/JSON) in the workspace, locate the workspace folder first and then locate the file and read from it using Node.js file related API.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for this. No wonder I was having so much trouble. Are you referring to a specific file related API? Or just letting me know I can use any of them? Thanks

Comment: use `vscode.workspace.fs` to read files, also works for virtual workspaces